# android ndk vector syntax error?

Tags: android, opencv, vector, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am using opencv | ndk | cdt in android, eclipse Juno Release. I set the project path as below.

```
${NDK}\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.6\include
${NDK}\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.6\libs\armeabi-v7a\include
${NDK}/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include
```

But when i use the vector,it shows some error. As the code below shows, the vector object matches, can't use some method, e.x. matches.at(0) or even matches[0] are both error.
But the method matches.empty() or matches.push_back() works well. So confused.

the cpp source code :

```
vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for(vector<DMatch>::iterator it = matches.begin(), it < matches.end(), it ++){

}

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}
```

also, the code above:

```
//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for(vector<DMatch>::iterator it = matches.begin(), it < matches.end(), it ++){

}
```

When press F3 to go definetion of vector, eclipse shows vector syntax error !!! And let me to choose the position to go .

Any suggestion will be appreciated. THX

Comment: Which C++ runtime did you select by defining APP_STL inside your
Application.mk?

Comment: @auselen ok, i solved this. Seems change the path 4.6 to 4.4.3 in ndk. That's strange. thank'u